# Android - Square view taking all available space

Tags: android, constraints

I am trying to make a layout, that will have one square view (A) and one other view of constant height (B) right below the square view. View A should expand as much as visible, but both views must be fully visible. Extra space should be either on the sides, or under View B (depends on the screen dimensions).

I tried to play with Constraint layout (app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"), but without success.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Any ideas please?

Comment: post your xml, let use see what you tried

Answer (score 0):

this will do your work change the percentage in the guideline to how much space you want to divide them into.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutA"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_tTopOf="@id/guidelinev1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">


//Put your textViews here

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/ LinearLayoutB"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottompOf="@id/guidelinev1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf ="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">


//Put your textViews here

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelinev1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```